# responsive CSS without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, landscape-portrait

I'm developing a webpage, and I have a CSS file for landscape and one for portrait view, but on mobile device when I start to type in a text box in portrait mode then automatically change to landscape. How can I fix this?

I know about bootstrap but that's too late for me, because I have too many pages, so I need a solution without that if it is possible.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _"when I start to type in a text box in portrait mode then automatically change to landscape"_ - you must of written the code to make this happen. How can you not know how to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many services to resolve this. 
You can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/getting-started.html)  for both e-mails and sites or [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/). If you want to use as react component than maybe [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) is the best. If you want to use many animations you can get [UIkit](https://getuikit.com/). For just simple things the [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) is the best, it's simple, fast, but not as smart as other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap can only make your life easy. Additional, you can use media queries for your different devices resolutions and orientation...
This repository is one of the best resource for identify the media queries:
[CSS media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com)